# Pasar los datos de un cuadro de diálogo o evento Schedule de un JSF a otro

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Uso *Primefaces 6.0*, *JSF 2.2*, *NetBeans* y *MySQL*. La idea es que la aplicación permita agendar los casos desde un `Schedule` a partir de un cuadro de dialogo. Después de ser creado me gustaría que al abrir el cuadro del dialogo a partir de un `button` de `"Detalles del CDC"` se redireccione a otra vista *JSF* (otro *XHTML*) donde se va a poder incluir mayor información sobre el caso y que se pueda descargar el adjunto (incluido en la fase del cuadro de dialogo).

Anexo vista con `Schedule` y `Dialog`:

```
<div id="top" class="top">
    <ui:insert name="top">
        <ui:include src="/Templates/MenuBar.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
<div id="content" class="center_content">
    <ui:insert name="content">
        <h:form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:growl id='msgGrowl' showDetail='true'/>
            <p:schedule
                id = "scheduleCdc"
                value="#{cdcBean.scheduleModel}"
                widgetVar="scheduleCdc"
                locale='es'
                timeZone="America/Caracas"
                resizable="true" aspectRatio="2.8"
            > 
                <p:ajax
                    event="eventSelect"
                    listener="#{cdcBean.selectCdc}"
                    update="cdcDetail"
                    oncomplete="PF('boxDialog').show();"
                />
                <p:ajax
                    event="dateSelect"
                    listener="#{cdcBean.selectNewCdc}"
                    update="cdcDetail"
                    oncomplete="PF('boxDialog').show();"
                />
                <p:ajax
                    event="eventMove"
                    listener="#{cdcBean.moveCdc}"
                    update="scheduleCdc"
                />
                <p:ajax
                    event="eventResize"
                    listener="#{cdcBean.resizeCdc}"
                    update="scheduleCdc"
                />
            </p:schedule>
            <p:dialog
                widgetVar="boxDialog"
                header="Control de Cambio"
                resizable="true"
                modal="true"
                showEffect="click"
            >
                <p:outputPanel id="cdcDetail">
                    <p:outputLabel
                        value="Número del CDC: "
                        rendered="#{cdcBean.cdc.idCdc gt 0}"
                    />
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{cdcBean.cdc.idCdc}"
                        rendered="#{cdcBean.cdc.idCdc gt 0}"
                    />
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Título"/>
                        <p:inputText
                            value="#{cdcBean.cdc.description}"
                            required="true"
                        />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Desde: "/>
                        <p:calendar
                            value="#{cdcBean.cdc.dateStart}"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                            required="true"
                        />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Hasta: "/>
                        <p:calendar
                            value="#{cdcBean.cdc.dateEnd}"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
                            required="true"
                        />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Documentación: "/>
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:fileUpload
                                uploadLabel="Adjuntar"
                                fileUploadListener="#{cdcBean.elegirArchivo}"
                                value="#{cdcBean.cdc.document}"
                                fileLimit="1"
                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(docx|doc|pdf|png|PNG)$/"
                                cancelLabel="Cancelar"
                                id="fileupload"
                                label="Elegir"
                                mode="advanced"
                                update="nombreDocumento"
                                sizeLimit="10000000"
                                invalidFileMessage="Tipo de archivo no válido"
                                invalidSizeMessage="El archivo supera los 10 Mb"
                                rendered="#{cdcBean.cdc.rutaDocument eq null}"
                            />
                            <p:outputLabel
                                id="nombreDocumento"
                                value ="#{cdcBean.cdc.rutaDocument}"
                            />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Interrupción: " />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                            id="check"
                            value="#{cdcBean.cdc.interruption}"
                            onclick="hideOrShow(this.checked);"
                        /> <!--onclick="hideOrShow(this.checked);"-->
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGroup
                        id="myPanel"
                        style="display: none;"
                    > <!--style="display: none;"-->
                        <p:outputLabel value="Tiempo de Interrupción: " />
                        <p:inputText
                            id="content"
                            value="#{cdcBean.cdc.timeInterruption}"
                        />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                        <p:commandButton
                            value="Guardar"
                            actionListener="#{cdcBean.saveCdc}"
                            update='msgGrowl
                            scheduleCdc' oncomplete="PF('boxDialog').hide();"
                        />
                        <p:commandButton
                            value="Borrar"
                            type="reset"
                            update="boxDialog"
                            immediate="true"
                        />
                        <p:button
                            icon="ui-icon-search"
                            value="Detalles del CDC"
                            rendered="#{cdcBean.cdc.idCdc gt 0}"
                            outcome="CreateCDC"
                        >
                            <f:param name="idCdc" value="#{cdcBean.cdc}"  />
                        </p:button>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
```

El `Bean` asociado:

```
@PostConstruct
public void begin() {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Log de prueba, begin");

    cdc = new Cdc();
    scheduleModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    cdcDao = new CdcDao();

    try {
        cdcList = cdcDao.getCdcList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CdcBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Error")
        );
    }
    for (Cdc c : cdcList) {
        DefaultScheduleEvent evt = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
        evt.setTitle(c.getDescription());
        evt.setStartDate(c.getDateStart());
        evt.setEndDate(c.getDateEnd());

        try {
            evt.setData(c.getIdCdc());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CdcBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        evt.setEditable(true);

        if (c.isInterruption()) {
            evt.setStyleClass("utilisateur1-event");
        }
        Logger.getLogger(
            getClass().getName()
        ).log(Level.INFO, "style class: {0}", evt.getStyleClass());
        scheduleModel.addEvent(evt);
    }
}
public void selectCdc(SelectEvent selectEvent) throws Exception {
    Logger.getLogger(
        getClass().getName()
    ).log(Level.INFO, "Seleccionando Evento en Calendario");
    ScheduleEvent event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    for (Cdc c : cdcList) {
        if (c.getIdCdc() == (int) event.getData()) {
            cdc = c;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Vista a donde deseo pasar la información:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="idCdc" value="#{cdcBean.cdc}"  />
</f:metadata>
<h:body>
    <div id="top" class="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">
            <ui:include src="/Templates/MenuBar.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="left_content">
        <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Datos del CDC" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <p:messages id="messages" />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="Número del CDC: " />
                    <h:outputText  value="#{cdcBean.cdc.idCdc}"/><p></p>
                    <h:outputText value="Estatus " />
                    <h:outputText  value="Generado"/><p></p>
                    <!-- <p:outputLabel for="datetime" value="Fecha Inicio: " />
                    <p:calendar
                        id="datetime"
                        value="#{cdcBean.cdc.dateStart}"
                        pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" locale="es"
                    />
                    <p:message for="datetime" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="datetimeend" value="Fecha Fin " />
                    <p:calendar
                        id="datetimeend"
                        value="#{cdcBean.cdc.dateEnd}"
                        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    />
                    <p:message for="datetimeend" />-->
                    <p:outputLabel for="time" value="Duración del CDC" />
                    <h:outputText id="time" value="#{cdcBean.cdc.time}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Interrupción de Servicio: " />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cdcBean.cdc.interruption}" />
                    <p/>
                    <p:outputLabel
                        for="timeInterruption"
                        value="Duración de la Interrupción: "
                    />
                    <h:outputText
                        id="timeInterruption"
                        value="#{cdcBean.cdc.timeInterruption}"
                    />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando el mismo bean para ambas páginas, cierto? De ser así, ¿cuál es el scope que le has puesto al bean?

Comment: Listo, según lo comentado por Mendoza revise de nuevo mis anotaciones scoped y era eso. Estaba usando `@ViewScoped`, la cambie a `@ApplicationScoped` porque es la que mejor se adapta a mi requerimiento.

Comment: En efecto estaba utilizando el scoped inadecuado.

Answer (score 1):

Yo si uso managedBean de alcance @ViewScoped y me ha funcionado, de esta manera

Este es mi calendario temgo un dialog donde puedo perdir la información extra que necesito para el evento

**.xhtml**

```
 <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{agendaAudienciaMB.schedule}"  widgetVar="myschedule" timeZone="America/Guatemala" 
                    locale="es" minTime="7:00" maxTime="18:00" draggable="false" resizable="false">  
            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{agendaAudienciaMB.onEventSelect}" update="@form" oncomplete="PF('eventDialogAudiencia').show();"   />
 </p:schedule>
```

En el ManagedBean declaro tres variables que se utilizan para el mejor manejo del calendario, si tienes alguna duda sobre los metos estan en la documentación oficial de [primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml)

```
private ScheduleModel schedule;
private ScheduleModel lazyEventModel;
private ScheduleEvent audiencia = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
    return schedule;
}

public ScheduleModel getLazyEventModel() {
    return lazyEventModel;
}

public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (audiencia.getId() == null) {
        schedule.addEvent(audiencia);
    } else {
        schedule.updateEvent(audiencia);
    }

    audiencia = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
}

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    audiencia = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    audiencia.getDescription();
    fechaAudiencia = (RdFechaAudiencia) audiencia.getData();
    log.debug("Evento seleccionado: " + fechaAudiencia.toString());
    Response<RdFechaAudiencia> response = audienciaBean.findFechaAudienciaById(fechaAudiencia.getIdFechaAudiencia());
    if (response.isOk()) {
        fechaAudiencia = response.getValue();
    }
}

public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    audiencia = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
}

public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Fecha movida", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Evento ampliado", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}
```